# If a primary key is NOT NULL, then should a foreign key that references it be specified also as NOT NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

Suppose I have something like

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    .
    .
    .
);

CREATE TABLE Bar (
    .
    .
    foo_id INT REFERENCES Foo(id),
    .
    .
);
```

Do/should I instead have

```
foo_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Foo(id)
```

or is that implicit in the fact that the value it's referencing is guaranteed to be `NOT NULL`?

Comment: FK is a reference not a constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The foreign key column on `Bar` can be `NULL`, if it's possible that a `Bar` record may exist without that value.

> the fact that the value it's referencing is guaranteed to be NOT NULL

If the value in `Bar` is `NULL` then it's simply not referencing a record in `Foo`.  It *can* reference a record, but doesn't have to if it allows `NULL`.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not necessary and it's by purpose. You can still put a `NULL` value into foreign key and it means that it actually doesn't reference anything.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, generally FK's are created on primary key of the referencing table and so in your case if `foo_id` is supposed to be a PK then it has to be defined with `NOT NULL` constraint else yes it can allow `NULL` like what you have now

```
foo_id INT REFERENCES Foo(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, No.
The primary key must be not null to be a primary key.

The foreign key may be null no problem